# How to compare two percentage number

Tags: expressions

Let's say A=10%, B=15%. How can I express how much higher B is than A.
I can not say "B is 5% higher than A", because that means B=(1+5%)*A.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would say B is 5 *percentage points* higher than A.

From [the percentage point article](https://everipedia.org/wiki/lang_en/Percentage_point) on Everipedia:

> Consider the following hypothetical example: In 1980, 50 percent of the population smoked, and in 1990 only 40 percent of the population smoked. One can thus say that from 1980 to 1990, the prevalence of smoking decreased by 10 **percentage points** (or by 10 percent of the population) or by 20 **percent** when talking about smokers only - percentages indicate proportionate part of a total.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on a number of factors. There are essentially three options I can think of that should cover most situations.

> - A is 10%, and B is 15%

This is as unambiguous as you can get.

> - B is 5% more than A
> - B is 50% more than A

These work if A is known as a percentage, but are ambigious - the hearer has to guess at the meaning, Perhaps the context will be useful, but otherwise, you can't tell whether B is 15%, 10.5%, or 60%.

In brief, in English, I don't think there's an idiomatic way to unambiguously phrase the idea you want without stating both values.

Comment: Thank you! Then how do you usually say when you compare something like increasing rate? "The increasing rate of GDP this year is 5% higher than that of last year" is ambiguous.

Comment: You really can't say B is 5% more than A, even if you are purposefully vague about A being a percentage. B can not be both 50% more and 5% more than A. It's 5 percentage points higher.

Comment: @leetom I think that you could possibly say _GDP has increased 5%_, which I think is unambiguous.

Comment: @ColleenV I don't see why not; when you're talking about percentages, it's all about whether the percentage is expressing a proportion of A, or of the thing that both A and B refer to. Without that referent, B can be 5% (of the thing) more than A, and also 50% (of A) more than A.

Comment: Maybe my background in Engineering makes me see ambiguity where most people would understand the meaning. If you read your two example sentences they say completely different things to me. If you say B is 5% more than A, how does the reader know whether you're talking about percentage points or a percentage? Maybe if it was spelled out "The percentage of B is 5 percent higher than A." I see this confusion between percent and percentage points in video games where players think +100% chance to hit is % chance to hit plus 100% not double the % chance to hit.

Comment: @Col yeah, that seems reasonable. But the ambiguity in those sentences  is precisely the point of the question, and exactly why I identify them as such. I'll edit the answer, though, since their ambiguity isn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

You could say B is 50% more than A
OR
You could say "B is 5% more" (without making a reference to A)

Comment: It is meaningless to say that *B is 5% more* with no further information.